# Send JsonResponse with related objects

Tags: python, json, django

I want to send JsonResponse with related objects. Here's my playground.

I do it as

```
def get_stocks(qty=9):
  return Stock.objects.values()[:9]

# Returning stocks
stocks = api_services.get_stocks()
return JsonResponse(list(stocks), safe=False)
```

My models are like

```
class Sector(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
  original_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  slug = models.CharField(max_length=200) 

class Industry(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
  original_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)   

class Stock(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  ticker = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
  logo = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
  website = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
  sector = models.ForeignKey(Sector, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  
  industry = models.ForeignKey(Industry, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

How can I get my json with related objects? Now I get

```
0   Object { id: 1, name: "Tesla", ticker: "TSLA", … }
id  1
name    "Tesla"
ticker  "TSLA"
logo    null
website "http://www.tesla.com"
sector_id   1
industry_id 1
```

I need to get sector and industry as well

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look up the model entry for the given ID in the Stock model. You can do that in your get_stocks method. Another option would be using a Stock [serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/).
For example:

```
def get_stocks(qty=9):
   stocks = Stock.objects.all()[:qty]
   for stock in stocks:
      try:
         stock.sector = Sector.objects.get(id=stock.sector)
      except Sector.DoesNotExist:
         pass
     
      try:
         stock.industry = Industry.objects.get(id=stock.industry)
      except Industry.DoesNotExist:
         pass

   return stocks
```